# scroll lag in Custom ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

My project is a tuition management book in this I list all students with their photos, names, IDs, classes in Activity by using a custom listView it runs well but when adding more student it showing  lag in listview scrolling. using the below adapter I am facing scroll lag in listView. I reduce the size of the image(under 500kb)which store in the SQLite database but still it's not working smoothly. **

> Adapter code

```
public class MyListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
   private Context context;
   private int layout;
   private ArrayList<slmodel> recordlist;

    public MyListAdapter(Activity context, int layout, ArrayList<slmodel> recordlist) {
        this.context = context;
        this.layout= layout;
        this.recordlist = recordlist;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return recordlist.size();
    }

    @Override
    public slmodel getItem(int position) {
        return recordlist.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    private class ViewHolder{
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView name,id, sclass;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row=convertView;
        ViewHolder holder=new ViewHolder();

        if(row==null)
          {
              LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
              row=inflater.inflate(layout,null);
              holder.name=row.findViewById(R.id.bname);
              holder.id=row.findViewById(R.id.sid);
              holder.sclass =row.findViewById(R.id.scourse);
              holder.imageView=row.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
              row.setTag(holder);
          }
        else{
            holder=(ViewHolder)row.getTag();
        }

        slmodel model=recordlist.get(position);
        holder.name.setText(model.getName());
        holder.id.setText(model.getId().toString());
        holder.sclass.setText(model.getsclass());

        byte[] recordimgae=model.getImgae();
        Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(recordimgae,0,recordimgae.length);
        holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        return row;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO, and congratulations on posting your first question.

#### use image loading libraries like [Picasso](https://square.github.io/picasso/) or [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

with these libraries, you can:

- resize your image
- use caches to decrease loading time
- handle background thread automatically for loading and converting bitmaps.

sample for Glide:

```
Glide.with(context)
                    .load(recordImage)
                    .asBitmap()
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                    .into(holder.imageView);
```

Comment: showing error at  .asBitmap() //Cannot resolve method 'asBitmap' in 'RequestBuilder'

Comment: thank brother its work now......for bitmap it write as-> Glide.with(context)
                .asBitmap().load(recordImage)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .into(holder.imageView);

Comment: @mihirSharma good, and more than that, try to replace your `ListView` with a `RecyclerView`. it improves performance for long lists.

Comment: @MihirSharma it would be nice of you if you select the answer as the accepted answer or upvote it